# $dy/dx=(1/2)y^{1/2}, y>0$ (differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{1/2}}{2}, \quad y>0$$

Here is what I tried:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{y^{1/2}}{2} \\
2y^{1/2}dy &= dx\\
6y^{3/2} &= x+c\\
y &= \sqrt[3/2]{\frac{x+c}{6}}
\end{split}
$$
But this does not satisfy the original equation. What went wrong?

Comment: Please use Math-Jax and not images.

Comment: I don't know how to use math-jax

Comment: On the RHS, is it 1/2 or -1/2.

Comment: ^ Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Comment: Wow cool, is this what is known as latex?

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake. compare with

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}dy=\frac 12 dx$$

$$\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}=\frac 14 dx$$

$$d(\sqrt{y})=d(\frac x4+C)$$

$$\sqrt{y}=\frac 14 x+C$$

you can finish.

Comment: What are the steps to integrate $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$ ? Are you supposed to use this rule?: https://gyazo.com/ed46326f85fe14f80fc5b7628a597981

Comment: It's just the power rule...

Answer (score 1):

Relevant equation to integrate should be
$$
2y^{-1/2}dy = dx
$$
This integrates to
$$
x+C=4y^{1/2}
$$